# Can't do it just like that

Tags: meaning, idioms, adverbs

> a. You can't carry out a scientific experiment **just like that**. You
> need to use the proper method.

or

> b. You can't carry out a scientific experiment **in any old manner**. You
> need to use the proper method.

I looked up 'just like that and it seems to mean 'unexpectedly' and 'suddenly'.

The idea I want to express has got nothing to do with suddenness. The idea is that there is a proper way to do something. You can't go about it haphazardly.

I wondered if 'just like that' could have that meaning here. I suppose (b) does say what I want to say, but I am not sure it is natural.

You don't carry out a scientific experiment in a happy-go-lucky manner. You proceed according to a method. Not all methods are good.

Comment: 'Carrying out an experiment just like that' would imply 'quickly and casually' to me, rather than 'unexpectedly'. A more informal way of saying 'in any old manner' would be 'any old how'.

Comment: Why not "haphazardly" (which you use in your explanation)? I think that that word works very well.

Answer (score 1):

"just like that" can also indicate it is done without much thinking or planning.

From Collins

> You use just like that to emphasize that something happens or is done
> immediately or in a very simple way, often without much thought or
> discussion.

From Idioms Free Dictionary

> in just the way it happened or was stated; without any [further]
> discussion or comment. Sue: You can't walk out on me just like that.